# List of object to List of predetermined type

Tags: c#

How to convert an original list to an other one in the more generic way. The destination type is only known at runtime.

I tried the following, but I got a `List<object>` filled with element of DestinationType type.

```
    public static object ToList(List<object> original,Type destinationType)
    {
        return
            original
                .Select(v => Convert.ChangeType(v, destinationType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                .ToList();//List<object> is returned, I want a List<destinationType>
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(destinationType));

foreach (var element in original)
{
    var converted = Convert.ChangeType(element, destinationType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    list.Add(converted);
}

return list;
```

Code creates instance of `List<destinationType>` in runtime then adds all converted elements to it and returns it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make the method generic this is the best solution.

```
    public static object ToList<T>(List<object> original)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        return original
                     .Select(v => (T)Convert.ChangeType(v, type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                     .ToList();
    }
```

Else, Go with @Rafal's solution..

Comment: I can't make the method generic, I don't kwon the T until runtime